# Java Lambda Referencing Enclosing Object: Replace with Private Static Class?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

A Java lambda referencing an element from its enclosing scope holds a reference to its enclosing object. A contrived example, with lambda holding ref to MyClass:

```
class MyClass {
  final String foo = "foo";
  public Consumer<String> getFn() {
    return bar -> System.out.println(bar + foo);
  }
}
```

This is problematic if the lifetime of the lambda is long; then we've got a ref to MyClass that is long-lived, when it would have otherwise gone out of scope. Here we can optimize by replacing the lambda with a private static class, so that we're only holding a reference to the String we need rather than to the entire class:

```
class MyClass {

  private static class PrintConsumer implements Consumer<String> {

    String foo;

    PrintConsumer(String foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(String bar) {
      System.out.println(bar + foo);
    }
  }

  final String foo = "foo";

  public Consumer<String> getFn() {
    return new PrintConsumer(foo);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is super verbose and destroys the nice syntax we get from using (effectively final) variables from enclosing scope in lambdas. Is this technically optimal? Is there always a tradeoff here between nice syntax and the possibility of keeping a ref longer than necessary?

Comment: Use C++ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Comment: I think your assumption is incorrect. The lambda does not hold a reference to the MyClass, only to the string.

Comment: Do you have evidence that class instance is referenced in this case? It would be enough to reference that single String object.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: [That's not correct](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/11/10/beware-of-functional-programming-in-java/)

Comment: @user234461 I'm aware of lambda captures in C++; capturing discerningly from enclosing scope is a really nice feature.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you Lukas and apologies to @Noel

Comment: I can't see this referenced here, @LukasEder

Comment: Another reference: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html, "References to this -- including implicit references through unqualified field references or method invocations -- are, essentially, references to a final local variable. Lambda bodies that contain such references capture the appropriate instance of this."

Comment: @Ingo: `this` is referenced implicitly

Comment: @Noel Ok, I see. I thought they'd eta-expand and thus copy the variables at least.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Assign your member to a local variable first:

```
class MyClass {
  final String foo = "foo";
  private Consumer<String> getFn() {
    String localFoo = foo;
    return bar -> System.out.println(bar + localFoo);
  }
}
```

Now, the lambda only captures local variables inside of `getFn()`. `MyClass.this` is no longer captured.

#### Another option, slightly more verbose, delegate to a helper method:

```
class MyClass {
  final String foo = "foo";
  private Consumer<String> getFn() {
    return getFn(foo);
  }
  private static Consumer<String> getFn(String localFoo) {
    return bar -> System.out.println(bar + localFoo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. What I don't get is why the lambda needs to capture the enclosing `MyClass` instance if all it needs is `foo`, which is a `final String`. Seems like it could have only captured a string constant.

Comment: @AR.3: `foo` is a member reference from within the lambda. It needs to be resolved every time the lambda is invoked. For instance, it could be `null` if the lambda is invoked from the initialiser prior to `foo` being initialised. It could be changed again because of some reflection magic.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of implementing helper method delegation with Functions (or at least, how I implemented it)?

Comment: @srborlongan: I don't see any disadvantages, except, perhaps, readability? Higher order lambdas aren't  a very common thing (yet)

Comment: I’m wondering why this answer emphasizes the “effectively final” nature of the local variable. If you declare the local variable truly `final`, the fact that `foo` is a compile-time constant comes into play and the lambda expression will be non-capturing, allowing it to become a singleton in the current implementation.

Comment: @AR.3: When the lambda expression accesses `MyClass.foo` directly, it *does* use the compile-time constant rather than actually reading the field. The possibility of the field being not initialized yet or the presence of Reflection magic is *never* considered in Java. However, it still captures `this`, maybe to follow a certain rule like that any instance field access mandates the capturing of `this`, however, I can’t find that part inside the Java Language Specification.

Comment: @Lukas Eder: when `localFoo` is declared `final`, the field `foo` will never be read at runtime. Instead, the lambda expression will directly use `"foo"`, regardless of what `foo` really contains when you invoke `getFn()` (speaking of the first solution, of course). Even without declaring `localFoo` as `final`, it will be directly initialized with `"foo"`, not actually reading `foo`.

Comment: @Holger [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188878/why-does-a-lambda-need-to-capture-the-enclosing-instance-when-referencing-a-fina)'s a related question I asked. I still tend to think that in this specific case though, it could have avoided capturing the whole `MyClass` instance.

Comment: @Holger: What you're saying is true, but I'm not sure if this is really generally relevant here. The fact that `final String foo = "foo"` is a compile-time constant might just be a simplification for the sake of keeping this question simple.

Comment: I’m not judging whether it is relevant to this specific question (though it’s worth noting that the behavior might be different for the question as-written compared to a possibly different real-life code). However, AR3 brought this up in the first comment, and there was a comment addressing it needing a correction. I only noticed afterwards that AR.3 opened a new *specific* question regarding that and added a [more complex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36608257/2711488) there…

Answer (score 1):

A combination of Lukas Eder's local-final-variable and helper-method-delegation solutions:

```
class MyClass {
  final String foo = "foo";
  private Consumer<String> getFn() {
    return apply(
      foo,
      localFoo -> bar -> System.out.println(bar + localFoo)
    );
  }
  private static <IN, OUT> OUT apply(
    final IN in,
    final Function<IN, OUT> function
  ) {
    return function.apply(in);
  }
}
```