# Why does a lambda need to capture the enclosing instance when referencing a final String field?

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8

This is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187451/java-lambda-referencing-enclosing-object-replace-with-private-static-class). Consider this example where a method returns a `Consumer` based on a lambda expression:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        Consumer<String> fn = m.getConsumer();

        System.out.println("Just to put a breakpoint");
    }
}

class MyClass {
    final String foo = "foo";

    public Consumer<String> getConsumer() {
        return bar -> System.out.println(bar + foo);
    }
}
```

As we know, it's not a good practice to reference a current state inside a lambda when doing functional programming, one reason is that the lambda would capture the enclosing instance, which will not be garbage collected until the lambda itself is out of scope.

However, in this specific scenario related to `final` strings, it seems the compiler could have just enclosed the constant (`final`) string `foo` (from the constant pool) in the returned lambda, instead of enclosing the whole `MyClass` instance as shown below while debugging (placing the breaking at the `System.out.println`). Does it have to do with the way lambdas are compiled to a special `invokedynamic` bytecode?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify? You first explain that you expect the enclosing ``MyClass`` instance and afterwards you are surprised to see this ``args$1``

Comment: @JeanLogaert The question is *why* it still happens while using a final variable

Comment: @JeanLogeart The question relates specifically for `final String`, which is considered a constant.

Comment: " it's not a good practice to reference a current state inside a lambda when doing functional programming, since the lambda would capture the enclosing instance, which will not be garbage collected until the lambda itself is out of scope." This has nothing to do with functional programming. It has to do with optimization. The functional programming viewpoint would be that it is a bad practice to close over mutable state. The fact that closures extend the lifetimes of their captures is an essential part of how they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the lambda was capturing `foo` instead of `this`, you could in some cases get a different result. Consider the following example:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.consumer.accept("bar2");
    }
}

class MyClass {
    final String foo;
    final Consumer<String> consumer;

    public MyClass() {
        consumer = getConsumer();
        // first call to illustrate the value that would have been captured
        consumer.accept("bar1");
        foo = "foo";
    }

    public Consumer<String> getConsumer() {
        return bar -> System.out.println(bar + foo);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
bar1null
bar2foo
```

If `foo` was captured by the lambda, it would be captured as `null` and the second call would print `bar2null`. However since the `MyClass` instance is captured, it prints the correct value.

Of course this is ugly code and a bit contrived, but in more complex, real-life code, such an issue could *somewhat easily* occur.

Note that the only true *ugly* thing, is that we are forcing a read of the to-be-assigned `foo` in the constructor, through the consumer. Building the consumer itself is not expected to read `foo` at that time, so it is still legit to build it before assigning `foo` – as long as you don't use it immediately.

However the compiler will not let you initialize the same `consumer` in the constructor before assigning `foo` – probably for the best :-)

Comment: This is interesting to think about, but it tends to look more like a bug in the code itself.

Comment: @AR.3 the `bar1null` output would probably be considered a bug in the code, but I think you wouldn't expect the second call to print `bar2null`: that would be considered a bug in the JVM.

Comment: I agree with you. If one day, however, `final` fields are captured differently in a lambda, I wouldn't be surprised at all to see two `bar1null` in the output.

Comment: In this example, `foo` isn’t a compile-time constant. So it isn’t exactly what the question is about.

Answer (score 15):

In your code, `bar + foo` is really shorthand for `bar + this.foo`; we're just so used to the shorthand that we forget we are implicitly fetching an instance member.  So your lambda is capturing `this`, not `this.foo`.

If your question is "could this feature have been implemented differently", the answer is "probably yes"; we could have made the specification/implementation of lambda capture arbitrarily more complicated in the aim of providing incrementally better performance for a variety of special cases, including this one.

Changing the specification so that we captured `this.foo` instead of `this` wouldn't change much in the way of performance; it would still be a capturing lambda, which is a much bigger cost consideration than the extra field dereference.  So I don't see this as providing a real performance boost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The rationale is that it could reduce the number of potential "leaks" where lambdas retain references to enclosing instances (as Java 8 is more and more used), by only enclosing the instances if the field is not `final`.

Comment: FYI a few years back Neal was considering making some changes to the C# lambda capture code in this spirit; I don't know if he ever did.

Comment: Note also that this also requires careful tradeoffs.  Its obvious when a lambda has one reference to `this.x`, but what about two?  Three?  Ninety six?  At some point, the "cure" of capturing additional vars is worse than the disease.

Comment: Sorry, but this explanation misses the point. When analyzing the compiled code, we will find that it *does* use the compile-time constant value of `foo`, if the instance variable `foo` is a compile-time constant like in the question. Which is a good thing as this is consistent with every other access to that variable and we’re not talking about “optimization” at all. What’s interesting, is that it still captures `this` despite not using nor needing it. Maybe to fulfill a specification, but note that *the* specification doesn’t mention any field/this capturing rules. Or I couldn’t find it.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, it technically *could* do so, because the field in question is `final`, but it doesn't.

However, if it is a problem that the returned lambda retains the reference to the MyClass instance, then you can easily fix it yourself:

```
public Consumer<String> getConsumer() {
    String f = this.foo;
    return bar -> System.out.println(bar + f);
}
```

Note, that if the field hadn't been `final`, then your original code would use the actual value at the time the lambda is executed, while the code listed here would use the value as of the time the `getConsumer()` method is executed.

Comment: That's not strictly speaking correct. As other answers have noted, the semantics may be different due to the initialization order of instance members. Furthermore, although the field is in fact final, the lambda still in fact does reference the actual value at the time getConsumer was called. The final invariance is incidental.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any ordinary Java access to a variable being a compile-time constant, the constant value takes place, so, unlike some people claimed, it is immune to initialization order issues.

We can demonstrate this by the following example:

```
abstract class Base {
    Base() {
        // bad coding style don't do this in real code
        printValues();
    }
    void printValues() {
        System.out.println("var1 read: "+getVar1());
        System.out.println("var2 read: "+getVar2());
        System.out.println("var1 via lambda: "+supplier1().get());
        System.out.println("var2 via lambda: "+supplier2().get());
    }
    abstract String getVar1();
    abstract String getVar2();
    abstract Supplier<String> supplier1();
    abstract Supplier<String> supplier2();
}
public class ConstantInitialization extends Base {
    final String realConstant = "a constant";
    final String justFinalVar; { justFinalVar = "a final value"; }

    ConstantInitialization() {
        System.out.println("after initialization:");
        printValues();
    }
    @Override String getVar1() {
        return realConstant;
    }
    @Override String getVar2() {
        return justFinalVar;
    }
    @Override Supplier<String> supplier1() {
        return () -> realConstant;
    }
    @Override Supplier<String> supplier2() {
        return () -> justFinalVar;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConstantInitialization();
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
var1 read: a constant
var2 read: null
var1 via lambda: a constant
var2 via lambda: null
after initialization:
var1 read: a constant
var2 read: a final value
var1 via lambda: a constant
var2 via lambda: a final value
```

So, as you can see, the fact that the write to the `realConstant` field did not happen yet when the super constructor is executed, no uninitialized value is seen for the true compile-time constant, even when accessing it via lambda expression. Technically, because the field isn’t actually read.

Also, nasty Reflection hacks have no effect on ordinary Java access to compile-time constants, for the same reason. The only way to read such a modified value back, is via Reflection:

```
public class TestCapture {
    static class MyClass {
        final String foo = "foo";
        private Consumer<String> getFn() {
          //final String localFoo = foo;
          return bar -> System.out.println("lambda: " + bar + foo);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        final MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        Consumer<String> fn = obj.getFn();
        // change the final field obj.foo
        Field foo=obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0];
        foo.setAccessible(true);
        foo.set(obj, "bar");
        // prove that our lambda expression doesn't read the modified foo
        fn.accept("");
        // show that it captured obj
        Field capturedThis=fn.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[0];
        capturedThis.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("captured obj: "+(obj==capturedThis.get(fn)));
        // and obj.foo contains "bar" when actually read
        System.out.println("via Reflection: "+foo.get(capturedThis.get(fn)));
        // but no ordinary Java access will actually read it
        System.out.println("ordinary field access: "+obj.foo);
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
lambda: foo
captured obj: true
via Reflection: bar
ordinary field access: foo
```

which shows us two things,

1. Reflection also has no effect on compile-time constants
2. The surrounding object has been captured, despite it won’t be used

I’d be happy to find an explanation like, “any access to an instance field *requires* the lambda expression to capture the instance of that field (even if the field is not actually read)”, but unfortunately I couldn’t find *any* statement regarding capturing of values or `this` in the current Java Language Specification, which is a bit frightening:

We got used to the fact that *not* accessing instance fields in a lambda expression will create an instance which doesn’t have a reference to `this`, but even that isn’t actually guaranteed by the current specification. It’s important that this omission gets fixed soon…